# Update npm without npm

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm-windows

If I try to update my npm via `npm update -g npm` I'll get an error: `npm ERR! Unexpected token '.'`

Since this is a known bug: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4234. How do I upgrade my npm without having to use npm itself?

I am using Windows and nvm for Windows.

Versions:

```sh
PS> npm -v           
8.8.0
PS> node -v
v18.1.0
```

Comment: try re-install a new version of nodejs together with the bundled npm.  Then update the npm.

Comment: What version of npm you're using?

Comment: Reinstalling didn't change anything to the version numbers, but npm is running now. @S

Comment: But now nvm broke.